# How to prevent the UI from locking up in AIR while calling a process?

Tags: actionscript-3, air

My application is calling an native process and the updates are about once per second but the UI is mostly locked up during this time.

Oddly the text areas can have text typed in but the text inputs, buttons and UI are unresponsive except for briefly.

Is there a way to keep the UI responsive?

Comment: Do you have an [MCVE] that demonstrates the problem?  From what I see in the docs for AIR's external process handling, it should all be asynchronous.

Answer (score 1):

To execute code in background without blocking the GUI, the best solution is usually with workers: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Worker.html
 not sure how it behaves with native processes though.